# How do I export multiple Excel sheets to pdf while maintaining page break settings?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pdf

I'm attempting to export multiple sheets to pdf, but the pdf file does not maintain the page breaks. The code creates a file with 15 pages that should have 3 pages because the pdf ignores the page breaks in Excel. If I reduce the Array to one sheet then it works fine. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Sub Macro1()
    Dim sheetArray As Variant

    sheetArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    Sheets(sheetArray).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Desktop\Sample.pdf"

    End Sub
```